# accessing property in custom cell from TTTableLinkedItemCell

Tags: iphone, ipad, three20

I am having a small issue in my implementation of my custom cell. Basically in my custom cell subclass (subclass of TTTableLinkedItemCell)
I have a BOOL called options. I want to be able to use this BOOL inside my

```
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item {
```

but, it seems that it is not possible. Is there any work around for this?

The options is used to adjust the height of the cell dynamically, whether it's set or not

defines the height of the cell.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following in my function that is called:

```
CustomCell* cell = (CustomCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
((RKMappableObjectTableItem *)[cell object]).options = YES;
```

and in my rowHeightForObject I have:

```
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item {
    float optionsHeight = 0.0;
if (((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) item).options)
        optionsHeight = 25.0;
    }
```

Here's how I set it up:

```
@interface RKMappableObjectTableItem : TTTableLinkedItem {
    NSObject* _object;
    BOOL _options;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject* object;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL options;

+ (id)itemWithObject:(NSObject*)object;

@end
```

However the BOOL is always NO, it's as if it's never set.. Why is this?
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to make a custom class for your `TTTableViewItem`. The cell should really be "dumb" and only display the information contained in the custom item. So I would take your `options` bool and store it in the custom item subclass, not the custom cell. This is why the method exists as a class method and you are passed in the item, rather than an instance method.

Comment: I thought of this as well... and considering if there are other prettier options

Comment: This *is* the pretty option. It is easy to do, and separates the model from the view, true MVC style.

Comment: the issue is how do I set the options property in my TTTableViewItem from a function that I have defined in TTTableViewController? How do I get the TTTableViewItem?

Comment: put a break point on the options = YES line to make sure it is being called. The code here looks good.

Comment: and I checked from the debugger that options is set to YES, however why is it that during my rowHeightForObject is is NO? The only possible explanation is that it's not calling on the same object..?

Comment: I figured the issue, but did not know how to solve it. When first set the BOOL, the item (TTTableLinkedItem) address in memory is X and in the rowHeightForObject function it was on address Y. Thus the difference BOOL value, as one BOOL value is set in X and the other in Y, which hasn't been set and thus defaults to NO. How do I solve this?

Comment: Something is swapping out the table items, so put a break point in your item subclass and see what it is so you can stop it.

Comment: @coneybeare let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1561/discussion-between-adit-and-coneybeare)

Comment: are you saying in my TTTableItem class implementation? I don't see anything that could swap it as I just declare a property there

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item {
    BOOL boolValue = [(YourCustomCellClass *)item options];
    if (boolValue) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: item is not a custom cell class, the rowHeightForObject is at the cell implementation